# How to use *args in a function?

Tags: python, function, args

This may be a basic question, but unfortunately I was not able to get anything while searching.

I have a function which uses `*args` to capture arguments when the function is run on the command line.

An basic structure is given below :

```
def func(*args):
    <code starts>
    ...
    </code ends>

func("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")
```

The problem here is, the code works if I pass the arguments in the code file itself as seen in the above snippet. I was looking on how to actually run this code from command line with the arguments are below :

```
# python <file.py> arg1 arg2 arg3
```

For that, I understand that I should change the line 'func("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")' in the code file itself, but I'm not sure how it is.

Can someone please point out how I can correct this.

Thanks a lot

NOTE: Both the solutions worked, yes both are the same. Its a pity I can't accept both answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`sys.argv[1:]`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) will give you all commandline arguments as a list.

So you could do `func(*sys.argv[1:])` in your code to receive all the arguments. However, there is no good reason to use varargs - just make the function accept a list `args` and pass `sys.argv[1:]` directly.

Comment: In this case please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark icon on the left side :)

Answer (score 6):

You would use similar syntax when *calling* the function:

```
func(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Here the `*` before the `sys.argv` list expands the list into separate arguments.

The [`sys.argv` list](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) itself contains all arguments found on the command line, including the script name; slicing it from the second item onwards gives you all the options passed in without the script name.