# How to use *args in a python class?

Tags: python, class, init, args

I am trying to get some args working in a class, I already got it running in a function from [How to use *args in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767604/how-to-use-args-in-a-function).

I'm trying to get that function into a class but I don't seem to understand how to initialize that class which has an **init** function taking *args. The code is as following :

```
class classname(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        <code-snip>
        ...
        </code-snip>

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = classname()
    start()
```

So here I'm confused on what to do with 'start()'. Do I have to use 'start(*sys.argv[1:])' or 'start()'. Both doesn't seem to work. I want to get the *args which is expected in **init** to be passed properly.

Any pointers please.

Thanks a ton..

======

I'm sorry if I wasn't clear on detailing how it didn't work.

a) While using start(*sys.argv[1:])

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check.py", line 126, in <module>
    start(*sys.argv[1:])
TypeError: 'check' object is not callable
```

b) While using start(), I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check.py", line 126, in <module>
    start()
TypeError: 'check' object is not callable
```

These were the errors which came up.

@alko, yes you are correct. I was looking on how to get the *args in **init** passed properly.

Comment: read this question you understand the concept
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs

Comment: @MONTYHS The irritation obviously comes from the uncertainty which methods are called when, and not from the `*, **` stuff itself.

Comment: If I got a dime whenever I read "It doesn't seem to work" without any further explanation, I'd be rich.

Comment: imho this is clearly stated as `I want to get the *args which is expected in init to be passed properly.`

Answer (score 8):

Objects are instantiated by passing arguments to [class constructor](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__). They are in turn initalized with [`__init__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) function. In your example this would be

```
start = ClassName(*sys.argv[1:])
```

that expression is processed as follows:

1. New instance of classname is instantiated with `object.__new__(ClassName, *sys.argv[1:])` named `start` in local [namespace](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces). From now on `start` object may be referenced inside your `if __name__ == "__main__"` script.
2. Its contents are in turn initialized invoking `start.__init__(*sys.argv[1:])`. Note that args to `__init__` are the same passed to constructor.

And read [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for python naming convention. That is:

> **Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.**

Answer (score 0):

Your example contains a class which is first instantiated - which involves calling `__init__()` - and then called - which is done by calling `__call__()`.

So your stuff should be put in the call `start = classname(...)` in order to be passed to `__init__()`.

The call to the newly instantiated object will fail, however, unless it contains a `__call__()` method. **That would have been easier to answer if you had told us what**

> **Both doesn't seem to work.**

**exactly means.**